# How to join and perform an operation between JSON data in C#?

Tags: c#, json, linq-to-entities

I'm dealing with linq-to-entities, querying 2 different entities. One returns `data` and the other returns `addValues`, also I have references to both `NewtonSoft.Json` and `System.Data.Objets`:
`var query1` returns `data` and `var query2` returns `addValues`. Debugging I can see that:

```
data = [{"key":"tf","value":221},{"key":"ba","value":108}];

addValues = [{"key":"tf","value":2},{"key":"ba","value":1.5}];
```

How do I obtain a new string/object joining by **"key"** and performing an operation between the values from **data** and **addValues**?
The result of the query should be `calculatedResult`.

```
result = [{"key":"tf","value":221+2},{"key":"ba","value":108+1.5}];

calculatedResult = [{"key":"tf","value":223},{"key":"ba","value":109.5}];
```

---

***Important note:*** I can be sure that both arrays will have the same number of items, BUT not ordered by `key`

Comment: Are `data` and `addValues` strongly-typed? As it is it's pretty tough to answer your question because what you've posted isn't valid C#, we have no idea of the type(s) you're dealing with.

Comment: Sorry about that @CraigW. In fact those are the string representation of the JSON Objects. They are stored as strings in a DB. `key` is string and `value` is decimal

Comment: Any particular reason you need to store it as JSON in the database?  What you're asking becomes trivial if it were stored "normally"

Comment: I understand, @JamesThorpe. They come serialized from an external source.

Comment: Fair enough!  Do you have any objects in your code that represent them as actual types yet?  Or do you just treat them as `Dictionary<string, decimal>`?  Do you use a JSON library at all yet, ie are you tied to NewtonSoft or the built in Microsoft stuff etc?

Comment: Forgive me if this is a trivial suggestion, but have you taken a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm ? Perhaps that would give you the tools you need to write your query.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm dealing with linq-to-entities, querying 2 different entities. One returns ´data´ and the other returns `addValues`, and the result of the query should be `calculatedResult`. I have references to both `NewtonSoft.Json` and `System.Data.Objets`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @nlopedebarrios It's worth editing all that info into your question - comments are secondary here on SO - people are more likely to come up with a good answer if all the info is in the question.  Perhaps write it so that `data` and `addValues` are things generated by actual code, using your JSON as a string input into the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet will work, assuming that each element in `data` and `addValues` has both a `key` and `value` field.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string key;
    public float value;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = "[{\"key\":\"tf\",\"value\":221},{\"key\":\"ba\",\"value\":108}]";
        var addValue = "[{\"key\":\"tf\",\"value\":2},{\"key\":\"ba\",\"value\":1.5}]";

        var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(data);
        var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(addValue);
        var new_obj = (from a in obj1
                       from b in obj2
                       where a.key == b.key
                       select new Foo { key = a.key, value = a.value + b.value }).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new_obj, Formatting.Indented));

    }
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "key": "tf",
    "value": 223.0
  },
  {
    "key": "ba",
    "value": 109.5
  }
]
```

Comment: I think it will work @Mark Segal, thank you! I was editing the question for clarification when you posted your answer. I'll let you know